# Can I add a Bot Task to a Business Process that only runs once?

Tags: java, workflow, workfusion

I am trying to build a Business Process in Workfusion's platform that takes in 10 records as input data and passes them along 3 Bot Tasks, where the output of one Bot Task is the input of the next. The final bot tasks outputs the data to a Data Store using ORMLiteRepository.

I created another bot task (let's call it Bot Task 4) that takes in the data from the data store using ORMLiteREpositry. This works in isolation as part of its own Business Process (with no input data) but how do I use it in the original business process? Is there a rule that stops input data reaching Bot Task 4 and makes sure it only executes once? Thank you very much.

I tried using an if-else condition in the Java code of Bot Task 4 (to only execute if the Data Store was full) but that did not work, it only results in the Bot Task executing 5 times.